# Waiting Screen In MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I want to  show a loading screen when the user clicks a button to perform an action because the action takes 10 seconds to run.

I in my home controller I have a simple HTTP post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostMethod()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return View(); 
}
```

In my view I have:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@section featured {
    <div id="divLoading" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #666666; z-index: 30001; opacity: .8; filter: alpha(opacity=70);display:none">
        <p style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 45%; color: White;">
            Loading, please wait...<img src="../../Content/themes/base/images/ajax-loading.gif">
        </p>
    </div>

    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
                <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>
}

<button onclick="JavascriptFunction();">HTTPPost Button</button>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function JavascriptFunction() {
        var url = '@Url.Action("PostMethod", "Home")';
        $("#divLoading").show();
        $.post(url,function (res) {
            $("#content-wrapper").html(res);
            $("#divLoading").fadeOut(100);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Basically the Javascript function displays the "divLoading" div when the user hits the button. This works fine. The problem is that "divLoading" never disappears after the sleeping for 1 second is complete. So the screen just remained like it loading when it should return back to normal.

Is this:

```
return View()
```

line of the [HTTP] working properly? Or is it something with this line:

```
$.post(url, null, function () {
    //$("#PID")[0].innerHTML = data;
    $("#divLoading").hide();
});
```

Somewhere it is not recognizing that the view is returned and it should not show the divLoading anymore.

Comment: did you check if your javascript function is executing where you want to call hide

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the return View() line and when I execute it goes straight to the inactive div screen. I doesn't go to the javascript function.

Comment: just after hide(); put like alert, and see if it comes up

Answer (score 1):

just realized if you are calling and doing ajax request you most likely do not want to return view do somethink like

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostMethod()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return Content(""); 
        }
```

Comment: I do want to return a view.

Comment: the view will not render in javascript

Comment: Is there a way to make it work when you return a view?TY

Comment: Return a partial view result.

Answer (score 1):

All code are fine, but the problem is that the **view "PostMethod" don´t exist**, so the server is answering "**Error 500**", and this do that the function in javascript is not called.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine without any problem. Since you are hiding your progress bar inside the callback function, it will be executed once you receive a response from the server action method.

The only reason i could see this won't work is, you are getting some server error in your action method and you are getting a **500 Internal server error** as a response to your ajax call. Make sure you action method is executing without any errors. You may put some breakpoints in your action method and see what is going on there.

*If you do not have a proper view file for your action method, It will throw a 500 error.*

***Suggestion :*** I would always wrap my event code inside the jquery document ready function. Also i personally prefer to use unobutrusive validation.

Also, Since it is an ajax call you are making, A better output for your action method is a JSON structure.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostMethod()
{
    try
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return Json( new { Status="Success"});
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       //log error
       return Json( new { Status="Error"});
    }
}
```

which you can verify in your client to see whether everything is fine

```
$(function(){
    $("#SomeButtonID").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $.post(url,function(res){
          if(res.Status==="Success")
          {
             alert("Everything went fine");
             //Do whatever you want here
          }
       });
    });
});
```

Instead of JSON, If you want to return, It is not a big change. Just return your view instead of JSON.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostMethod()
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
   return View(); 
   //assuming you have the PostMethod.cshtml 
   //present in ~/Views/YourControllerName`directory
}
```

in your callback, you can use this response (essentially HTML markup) to show it in some part of your page.

```
$.post(url,function(res){
    $("#YourAnotherDivId").html(res);
    $("#divLoading").fadeOut(100);    
});
```

Comment: I want to return a view not JSON. I took out all the code I really have. In my actual code after the user hits the button I do some work and then return the model to the page so I want my last line to be return View(model);  but in my examply I made is simpler. Is there a way to make it work with returning a View?TY.

Comment: as long as you have the view file in it's location, It should be fine. Check the firebug console to see what is happening.

Comment: is it possible to give an example of how it would work using return View() instead of the JSON? Thanks again.

Comment: what you want to do with the returned view ? Show it in some place of your page ?

Comment: yes. In my real example I do return View(model);  where model has varaibles that are populated when the user hits the button.

Comment: what do you want to do with the result ?

Comment: I return View(model) because model will be populated with data that I show on the webpage.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46961/discussion-between-user3022875-and-shyju)

Comment: The $.post has a "res" parameter but if your code for the view there is now "res"?

Comment: `res` will have the response from the action method. use `console.log(res)` to see what you are gettting

Comment: But the ActionResult PostMethod() returns a view correct? It does not return anything nameed "res" it is just return View();

Comment: `res` is a javascript variable which holds the response from your ajax method once it finishes execution. you can give any name to your variable.

Comment: See the code above. I am still getting the waiting screen that is just sitting there and not disappearing.